# Matching variable mid string

Tags: python, parsing

I'm writing a parser to work up output files from a program, and the program can have 2 styles of output depending on how it is run. If the letters calcall show up in the output, I want one version of the parser to run or the other if the string doesn't show up. One potential problem is the surrounding letters may not always be the same. Here is an example of one 'opt=(calcall, maxcyc=5)'

I have tried just matching the statement calcall line by line, as well as attempting to use regex, which I am admittedly bad at.

```
with open('file.log', 'r') as tf:
    lines = tf.readline()
    if re.search('.+calcall.+', lines) == 1:
        coord2()
    else:
        coord1()
```

This code runs coord1() even with the statement calcall in the file

Comment: The regex may also not work right in some edge cases, If the line contains only "calcall" then your regex will not work right. You can use \bcalcall\b to fix this, if you want just the word calcall. The \b stands for word boundary.

Answer (score 1):

It is as simple as:

```
if "calcal" in line:
    coord2()
else:
    coord1()
```

But the solution you are trying is referring only to the first line of 'file.log'
You want that for each line?

Comment: Yeah, the statement doesn't show up until some N lines into the output files

Answer (score 0):

Function re.search() returns a object (if found a match), so you should   rewrite your if statement in following way:

```
with open('file.log', 'r') as tf:
    lines = tf.readline()
    if re.search('.+calcall.+', lines):
        coord2()
    else:
        coord1()
```

Answer (score 0):

> This code runs coord1() even with the statement calcall in the file

You are matching line-by-line, but you want to run one function or the other depending on whether *the whole file* contains your keyword, right?

Check the whole file for your keyword first, and then decide on the function to run:

```
hasCalcall = False

# open the file and look for your keyword line-by-line
with open('file.log', 'r') as tf:
    for line in tf.readlines():
        if 'calcall' in line:
            hasCalcall = True
            break

# By now you know whether the file contains the keyword
if hasCalcall:
    coord2()
else:
    coord1()
```

*Not sure it's what you meant, I would ask for precisions but I am not allowed to comment on questions.*

EDIT: Fixed typo, break out of loop when keyword is found

Comment: @Newcarsmell You're welcome!
I just made an adjustment so it stops reading when the keyword was found, be sure to include it.
Also, please consider upvoting since it worked for you :)

(the reason I can't comment is because I haven't accumulated enough reputation, so that would help :])

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('file.log', 'r') as tf:
    lines = tf.readline()
    if "calcall" in lines:
        coord2()
    else:
        coord1()
```

Just change the "if" statement in your code. You can remove the use of regex completely.